# Show that $S_{n}(\sigma_{n}f)=\sigma_{n}(f)$ where $\sigma_{n}(f)=\dfrac{1}{n+1}(S_{0}f+\cdots+S_{n}f)$.

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

I am reading a proof in harmonic analysis, and in the middle of the proof, the author seems to claim that

> If $$S_{n}(f):=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\widehat{f}(n)e^{ikx}=(D_{n}*f)(x),$$ where $D_{n}$ is the Dirichlet Kernel, and $$\sigma_{n}(f):=\dfrac{S_{0}(f)+\cdots+S_{n}(f)}{n+1}.$$ Then, $S_{n}(\sigma_{n}(f))=\sigma_{n}(f).$

He said:

> For all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have that $\sigma_{n}(f)$ is a trigonometric polynomial of degree at most $n$,so $S_{n}(\sigma_{n}(f))=\sigma_{n}(f)$.

I understand that $\sigma_{n}(f)$ is a trigonometric polynomial, but why does this imply the equality?

Thank you!

**Edit 1: [Complete Proof]**

After read the answer from **Thorogtt**, I managed to prove the claim. This proof is exactly what **Thorogtt** suggested, I just add more details for future users who are interested in this question.

We know that $\sigma_{n}(f)$ is a trigonometric polynomial with degree at most $n$, so $S_{n}(\sigma_{n}(f))=\sigma_{n}(f)$ must be true.

Indeed, consider $$g(x):=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}c_{k}e_{k}(x),\ \text{where}\ e_{k}(x):=e^{ikx}.$$

Then, the Fourier coefficient is defined by 
\begin{align*}
\widehat{g}(m):=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}g(x)e^{-imx}dx&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\Big(\sum_{k=-n}^{n}c_{k}e^{ikx}\Big)e^{-imx}dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k=-n}^{n}c_{k}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e_{k-m}(x)dx\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\cdot 2\pi\cdot c_{m}\ \text{by the orthogonality}\\
&=c_{m}.
\end{align*}

Therefore, the partial sum $$S_{n}(g):=\sum_{m=-n}^{n}\widehat{g}(m)e^{imx}=\sum_{m=-n}^{n}c_{m}e^{imx}=g(x),$$ as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$-th Fourier polynomial of a trigonometric polynomial of degree at most $n$ is the trigonometric polynomial itself. Say you have such a trigonometric polynomial given as
$$g\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},\,x\mapsto\sum\limits_{k=-n}^nc_ke^{ikx},\qquad c_{-n},...,c_n\in\mathbb{C}.$$
It's a good exercise to check that $\hat{g}(k)=c_k$ for $k$ from $-n$ to $n$ and $0$ otherwise, so $S_ng=g$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just edited the post to give a proof with details. Thank you for your brilliant answer :)